# How to return UTC datetime from ODataController?

Tags: odata, datetime-format

My ODataController returns json response like below:

```
{
    "@odata.context":"http://...","value":[
    {
        "Name":null,"Description":null,"CreatedDate":"2017-03-09T21:24:45.6865981-08:00","Id":"2"
    }]
}
```

The problem is I want to return UTC datetime for CreatedDate, not a DateTimeOffset like that. If I edit the DateTimeOffset datamember set method to convert to UTC time, then the return is good.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets created date.
/// </summary>
[DataMember]
public DateTimeOffset? CreatedDate
{
    get
    {
        return createdDate;
    }

    set
    {
        this.createdDate = value != null ? value.Value.UtcDateTime : value;
    }
}
```

But this approach is not ideal, is there anything more global can be configured?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

All I can suggest is either you work with DTOs,
That means you will parse the objects and then return it to the client.
Second option and the more common, is to let your server use server time of course, and Apply the Globalization settings on the client side.
Anyway leave your Classes clean, they don't have to worry about anything else except holding the data they created for.

Good luck